# How to view NSLog statement from iphone .app file

Tags: iphone

I have created one sample application , based on UIWebview sample and i added some NSLog statements to check whether the application run correctly ?

Its work fine.So i build the .app file and given to my friend.He is installed in his iphone via itunes.

Its work fine. How my friend can view the NSLog statement (What i added in the code)? Is this possible ? plz help me .

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this app from Apple can be downloaded by your friend so he can view the console logs on his iPhone:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851

Answer (score 3):

You can easily redirect your debug output to file inside of your bundle. Check [this](http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/01/09/redirect-nslog-to-a-file-on-the-iphone/).
Then your friend can just get the output file from application's bundle directory and send to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to view the NSLog statements for the application downloaded from itunes store.Login to your apple developer account and download the ios developer PDF file. Hope this will help you in the right track.

Comment: Ok.Is it any default etheral software in the mac ? Because i have write an code for sending and receiving data over wifi.I want to test whether my data really sending from my system or not ?  Is it possible ?

Comment: Do u mean sending request to remote server?

Comment: No i want to send data from my mac machine to another windows xp machine.My mac connected via wifi network and xp machine connected with LAN(Ethernet) Network.

Comment: I am sending my data to xp machine but it cannot receive my data.So i want to check whether my data has going out from my mac ? In xp machine it has etheral software , but it didn't receive my data and also not displayed my ip in etheral.

Comment: I have found the solution,my wifi is connected as subnetwork.So i cant send data from wifi to xp machine. I am working on iphone developement application.I am in tanjore,tamilnadu.

Answer (score 0):

See in the XCode Organizer (`Window`-> `Òrganizer`)
In your device, you have a `Device Logs` tab