# Crash logs in enterprise ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, crash-log

I would like to extract crash logs of those users who are using my enterprise app. In case of the App Store apps I can get this information from iTunes connect. Since there is no intervention of App Store in case of Enterprise deployment therefore not sure how to access this information.

Is there any Objective-C API through which I can access the crash logs with the application code and upload them on my server using a web-service?

Comment: Found a framework at http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/ this might help in order to fetch crash logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Objective-C API available to access iOS generated crash reports. The only way to automatically access them, is adding a crash reporting framework to your apps that also catches the crashes and let you send them to a service or your own server.

I highly recommend not engineering your own crash reporting or exception handling mechanism, since it is way too complicated to make it right and not introduce more dangerous problems that could e.g. cause your app users to loose data.

The second part of my answer here lists a few options, contains open source projects, services with open source SDKs and closed source options: [iOS crash log catch, debug info.. Catch and send via email to the Dev team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233388/ios-crash-log-catch-debug-info-catch-and-send-via-email-to-the-dev-team/8242215#8242215)

Comment: Thanks for the Descriptive answer Kerni

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK No.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/).

Very powerfull. Very pleasant to use.

Comment: I hate the way they make you install their framework: first install an app that always stay in your mac manu bar, they this app will automatically install the framework in your Xcode projet... and potentially make lot of stuff you won't see.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct your users to extract the logs from iTunes and send them to you. Take a look at the "Sending Crash Reports to a Developer" section of this document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Danial but my app users are non technical therefore can not rely on them to post the crash logs