# Writing to UserDefaults in applicationWillTerminate doesn't always work

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I'm trying to detect whether or not the app crashed the last time it ran.

In `applicationWillTerminate` I have the following code:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(false, forKey: CRASHED_KEY)
defaults.synchronize()
saveContext()
```

By setting the value to `false` I'm instructing the app that it was closed correctly.

In `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` I have the following code:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let crashedLastTime = defaults.bool(forKey: CRASHED_KEY)

if (crashedLastTime) {
    //Handle error
}

defaults.set(true, forKey: CRASHED_KEY)
defaults.synchronize()
```

By setting it to `true` when it launches, it will be `true` if it crashed.

This code is acting a bit weird when restarting the app from xCode since it apparently doesn't call `applicationWillTerminate`. This is not a problem however.

The problem I'm having is that in some cases it will start up and say that it crashed, even though I terminated the app properly.

Any idea as to why UserDefaults doesn't always save?

Comment: Try this, even though it in Obj-C, you can convert to swift and use: 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330411/ios-is-there-any-delegate-method-when-the-app-quits-due-to-any-crash