# MFMailComposeViewController shows empty view

Tags: ios, email, ios7, messageui

I am not sure if I understand `MFMailComposeViewController` correctly.  I am expecting a viewcontroller with an existing view to show up on my screen. I can see the FTViewController's view.  But the mail composer never appears.

I have simplified the original question to a bare minimum.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FTViewController *vc = [[FTViewController alloc]init];
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    ..
    }
```

**In FTViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FTTest *test = [[FTTest alloc] init];
    [test testmeup];
}
```

**FTTest**:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface FTTest : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@implementation FTTest

- (void)testmeup
{
    BOOL ok = [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail];
    if (!ok)
        return;
    MFMailComposeViewController* vc = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
    vc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Try checking if you can even send mail (it might not be configured) before presenting the view controller. You can also use it as a debug to tell you if that's the problem.
[canSendMail](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMailComposeViewController/canSendMail)

Comment: is there any email account in your mail?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

If I move the same code from `- (void)viewDidLoad` to an action-able method, it works like a charm.  Hence the user needs to press a button or take an action first for this to work.

```
- (IBAction)gogogo:(id)sender
{
    FTTest *test = [[FTTest alloc] init];
    [test testmeup];
}
```

I believe Apple has done this to make sure the user knows what emails are being sent out.
Originally I was going to utilize this approach for catching exceptions and send them via email to myself as explained in this [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237652/92153).

Maybe I am overlooking something, feel free to comment.

Comment: Exactly the same as what I said in the comment on my other answer; you were simply calling `testmeup` way too early. In `viewDidLoad`, just as in `application:didFinish...`, there is no interface yet. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any email account in your Mail? if all accounts are disabled or removed

```
[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]
```

returns NO, then Nothing come out.

Comment: I double checked and it can send mail.  `canSendMail` returns true.