# How to use swift to detect app crash?

Tags: swift, logging, crash

I am currently working on code to log a user's behavior in the app and to report crashes and the sequence leading up to them. I have one big problem, I do not know how to make my app detect if it has crashed. Does anybody know how to do this in swift? Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A post that discusses several other approaches can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220379/swift-natively-detect-if-app-has-crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a way to do this. When your app crashes it ceases to function and all processes stop. Usually any crash and diagnostic data is sent via the user settings panel.

Edit: There is an helpful post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242215/4891259

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know the app stops working when it crashes. What I'm looking to do is log certain things as the app is running and then on event of a rash send those logs to a specific place weather it be a server or a an email. Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to build a data model and bind that to each action.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with SwiftyBeaver Logger. Check at Github (https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver) and signup at https://swiftybeaver.com to detect & catch logs during release