# Show SKStoreReviewController only when there was no crash lately?

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics

I'd like to call `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` only when this specific user/app installation didn't have an app crash (lately).

So the question is, how do I know **in the app** that this app itself crashed at least once or lately?

I'm using Crashlytics. So the app could ask Crashlytics if I knew how. But an answer without Crashlytics would also be very welcome.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220379/swift-natively-detect-if-app-has-crashed/37220472

Comment: This looks good

Answer (score 0):

I put together a class to handle this based on the link I shared in the comment. This separates the logic that tracks 'crashes' into a reusable class that can be dropped into any project.

A few notes:

- This won't catch crashes that happen in the background.
- This simply sets a bool in UserDefaults to 'true' when the app launches that gets set to 'false' when the app closes normally. It feels kind of hacky to me but it should accomplish what you want to do.
- I put the check for app crashes in the ViewController code. You may want to check for crashes in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in case the app crashes before the view controller loads. Checking `appDidCrash()` resets the tracker in UserDefaults.

That being said, it will catch crashes that the user sees while using the app.

```
import Foundation

class CrashTracker {

    // variable to hold the key used to store the crash record in UserDefaults
    static let defaultsKey = "com.YOUR_BUNDLE_ID.crashRecord"

    init() {
        registerListeners()
    }

    // sets up listeners for the app entering the background or terminating
    func registerListeners() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredBackground), name: .UIApplicationDidEnterBackground
        , object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willTerminate), name: .UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func enteredBackground() {
        // app didn't crash, user closed the app so update UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: CrashTracker.defaultsKey)
    }

    @objc func willTerminate() {
        // app didn't crash, user closed the app so update UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: CrashTracker.defaultsKey)
    }

    static func appDidCrash() -> Bool {
        // get the current value
        let storedValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: CrashTracker.defaultsKey)
        // reset to true to track current launch
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: CrashTracker.defaultsKey)
        return storedValue
    }

}
```

Set it up in app delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var crashTracker = CrashTracker()

...
```

Then in your view controller (or wherever you want to show your alert, maybe as soon as the app launches... `applicationDidFinishLaunching`)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if CrashTracker.appDidCrash() {
        print("caught crash ---------")
    } else {
        print("No crash... all good")
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    }
}
```

I experimented with `DispatchSourceSignal` as it seemed like it would be a better/more reliable way to track crashes but could never get it to work with Swift 4. I could never get any of the event handlers to fire.

For reference here's a small sample implementation.

**THIS DID NOT WORK FOR ME** *I'm including it here for completeness in case anyone else wants to experiment with it further.*

```
class TrackCrashViaDispatch {

    var sigtrap: DispatchSourceSignal?
    var sigint: DispatchSourceSignal?
    var sigabrt: DispatchSourceSignal?
    var sigill: DispatchSourceSignal?
    var sigseg: DispatchSourceSignal?
    var sigfpe: DispatchSourceSignal?
    var sigbus: DispatchSourceSignal?
    var sigpipe: DispatchSourceSignal?


    init() {

        // handle obj-c exceptions
        NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
        }

        setupHandlers()
    }

    func setupHandlers() {

        print("Setting up handlers...")

        signal(SIGTRAP, SIG_IGN) // // Make sure the signal does not terminate the application.
        sigtrap = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGTRAP, queue: .main)
        sigtrap?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGTRAP")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigtrap?.resume()


        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) // Make sure the signal does not terminate the application.
        sigint = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGINT, queue: .main)
        sigint?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGINT")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigint?.resume()

        signal(SIGABRT, SIG_IGN)
        sigabrt = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGABRT, queue: .main)
        sigabrt?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGABRT")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigabrt?.resume()

        signal(SIGILL, SIG_IGN)
        sigill = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGILL, queue: .main)
        sigill?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGILL")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigill?.resume()

        signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_IGN)
        sigseg = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGSEGV, queue: .main)
        sigseg?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGSEGV")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigseg?.resume()

        signal(SIGFPE, SIG_IGN)
        sigfpe = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGFPE, queue: .main)
        sigfpe?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGFPE")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigfpe?.resume()

        signal(SIGBUS, SIG_IGN)
        sigbus = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGBUS, queue: .main)
        sigbus?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGBUS")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigbus?.resume()

        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)
        sigpipe = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGPIPE, queue: .main)
        sigpipe?.setEventHandler {
            print("Got SIGPIPE")
            TrackCrashViaDispatch.registerCrash()
            exit(0)
        }
        sigpipe?.resume()
    }

    static func registerCrash() {
        print("Registering crash")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "com.YOUR_BUNDLE_ID.crashRecord")
    }

    static func appDidCrash() -> Bool {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        // get the current value
        let storedValue = defaults.value(forKey: "com.YOUR_BUNDLE_ID.crashRecord")
        // set to nil to track next time
        defaults.set(nil, forKey: "com.YOUR_BUNDLE_ID.crashRecord")

        return storedValue != nil
    }
}
```

I tried this second solution using different queues for the handlers, removing the ignore call `signal(SIGILL, SIG_IGN)` for each handler and making the vars global. Either I don't understand `DispatchSourceSignal` well enough or this approach just doesn't work.