# Is there a way to get the crash reports and the reason for which our code crashed in .txt file or .doc file saved within our application?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is it possible to create a crash log .txt file within a app that refreshes itself with the crash reports every-time our app get crashed.

Comment: Try with: https://try.crashlytics.com/ It's better for tracking your crash log

Comment: yes i have used crashlytic for getting crash log but what I want is to save the crashlog within my app in a txt file.

Comment: A_Curious_developer see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233388/ios-crash-log-catch-debug-info-catch-and-send-via-email-to-the-dev-team

Answer (score 2):

General answer is YES.There are already crash log for it.

Case 1.There are two scenarios,first you want to use it while developing or want user to send you the crash log.

When ever a device (iPhone,iPad etc) are synced with a mac crash log get stored in

**Mac OS X** : ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
**Windows XP**: C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/
**Windows7** : C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

Case2 If you want to get crash reports from a app on store and you want to retrieve it automatically then you can use https://try.crashlytics.com/

Answer (score 2):

Click show the report navigator which show every build's crash report in Xcode(Last Message like button)

[image: Click show the report navigator which show every build's crash report in Xcode]

[image]

Then you can check exact bug. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know to create but i can find logs in mac os

```
link - /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>
```

and see this link its help you
because it provide many online site which see the crash occur on client side 
and show the exact time and line where crash occur

http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1